# Unexpected Behavior in T-SQL OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Ran into some interesting behavior with the `OUTER APPLY` clause in T-SQL. See the below query.

Both columns `Total` and `Amount` are from the `OUTER APPLY`, however, the `Total` (which uses `COUNT(*)`) has a value for all 3 rows in Table1, even the row (C) that doesn't have any matching record(s) in Table2.

However, the `Amount` column (which behaves as I would expect) only has a value when there is a matching row in Table2, with the remaining rows having a `null` value.

The second `SELECT` query is performing the same functionality, except using an aggregate in the subquery and a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

I'm confused...

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
( 
     Col1 VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C');

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
( 
     Col1   VARCHAR(100)
   , Amount MONEY
);

INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES ('A', 100), ('B', 200);

SELECT *
FROM @Table1
OUTER APPLY
     (
         SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
              , SUM(Amount) AS Amount
         FROM @Table2
         WHERE [@Table1].Col1 = [@Table2].Col1
     ) AS Counts;

SELECT *
FROM @Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (
         SELECT Col1
              , COUNT(*) AS Total
              , SUM(Amount) AS Amount
         FROM @Table2
         GROUP BY Col1
     ) AS Counts ON [@Table1].Col1 = Counts.Col1;
```

Comment: See [Paul White on this](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html), the outer apply is using a scalar aggregate, which always returns 0. The join version uses a vector aggregate which returns no row

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `group by`

```
SELECT *
FROM @Table1
OUTER APPLY
     (
         SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
              , SUM(Amount) AS Amount
         FROM @Table2
         WHERE [@Table1].Col1 = [@Table2].Col1
         group by [@table2].col1  -- or group by () which is the same thing
     ) AS Counts;
```